# Moving a PHP Project from Linux to Windows using Docker?

Tags: php, docker, virtual-machine

I've been using Ubuntu dual booted with Win 10 for the past 2 years and I absolutely love ubuntu, however, due to my studies, I need frequently to use softwares like Excel, PowerBI, MiniTab, which only work on windows and have no good support through Wine unfortunately.
Currently I'm considering moving back to Windows, it's still good, but I don't want to waste a lot of time configuring PHP and JS for a project I'm working on on Ubuntu.

This project is based on Laravel 8, VueJS and MySQL for the database and I'm looking at the most efficient way to import this project to windows.

**Using  VirtualBox :**

I thought about installing ubuntu as a VM on Windows and reinstall all dependencies on that VM and code directly from the VM, but I have around 8 gb od RAM and a cpu I5 4th gen, with only HDD drive. I don't know if I will be comfortable coding on the VM with these specs, especially I will be running chrome and PHP Storm at the same time on the VM which can get up to 5gb of ram alone back on ubuntu.So I won't have any left for windows.

Any other solution ? I thought about using Docker, I don't know if it's  suitable in this case ?  like importing the project into a docker container in ubuntu, then move back to Windows and use that docker container in php storm or another IDE ?
I also tried WSL with no success since my linux partition is not a physical one.

What's the best solution given my specs to keep working on this project without leaving windows and can be set up easily ?

Comment: Have you heard about [WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Comment: Yes I tried it, but the problem is that my Ubuntu partition is not a physical one, and apprently I can't mount that ? (Linux was installed in the D:// parition back then when I did the dual boot)

Comment: I dont understand your problem. To my understanding PHP is platform agnostic. The PHP interpreter will parse and run it no matter what platform your on. The main diffrence will be line breaks and directory seperator.
In general you only need a server (like xampp) and change the connection data for your  mysql server.

Comment: @CodeSpirit to simplify it, is it less painful to reinstall PHP and dependencies on windows or just use a docker container of the project and run it (and work on it) in windows ?

Comment: Easiest is to just install xampp to get mysql apache and php with configuration. Then for dev server u just use the php server which is totally fine `php -S localhost:8000 -t public` and then start mysql server.